# Centering buttons with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

Basically I have a horizontal `div` in which buttons (in this code called letters) are created. But the problem is, that the buttons get aligned to the left side of the `div` and won't center. I have tried using the `text-align:center` in the CSS document under the label `#letter`, but it still won't center the buttons.

In case you need it, here is the part of code where the buttons get created:

```
// Makes letters for the chosen word.
function letterMaker() {
    for (i=0; i<word.length; i++) {
        var letter = document.createElement("input");
        var letters=(shuffledWord).split("");
        letter.type = "submit";
        letter.value = letters[i];
        letter.id = "letter" + i;
        letter.onclick = letterClick.bind(this, letter.value);
        letter.setAttribute('id', 'letter');
        document.getElementById("letterbar").appendChild(letter);
    }
}
```

And here is the part of code where the attributes are specified:

```
#letter {float:left;height:60px;width:60px;background-color:#C0C0C0;border-color:#000000;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-radius:5px;font-size:25px;font-family:century gothic}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd wager a guess you're setting the align on each element, instead of the container.

Try `#letterbar { text-align: center;}`

[MDN spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) says *text-align does not control the alignment of block elements itself, only their inline content.*

I know this is kind of tangential and not very helpful with the issue at hand, but consider using 'class' instead of 'id'. W3 spec ([HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align), same for HTML4, but my rep is too low to post more than 2 links - which is a pointless restriction) says `id` must be unique in document, and your loop spits out multiple inputs with the same `id`.

JSFiddle example: http:// jsfiddle.net/UuxuX/

**Edit**

As I've said in a comment, if you `float` the inputs to the left, `text-align` is nullified. If all you want to do is center the inputs in a div, drop the float from input and text-align the div.

Comment: In my case I use the #letterbar only to find the proper location for the letters to be inserted, properties themselves are specified in a separate class. Anyway, adding text-align:center to it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Care to share an example of what your HTML and CSS is, preferably in JSFiddle form? Also - it just dawned on me - you're floating the letters, right? That's the issue. Is the float *absolutely* necessary?

Comment: Have no need in sharing the example anymore, because after removing the float:left attribute, the letters now align properly in the center, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Place the buttons inside a `<div>` with `margin: auto;` inside the `div#letterbar`.

Comment: Do you mean that I should add the margin:auto; property into the letterbar? That still won't center the buttons.

Comment: No, inside a `div` inside `div#letterbar`

Answer (score 0):

Set the margin to `auto` in your css:

```
#letter {margin:auto;...}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with **JanParowka** what he said in earlier post.

If id of div is letterbox then you should do

> **#letterbox { text-align: center;}**